# Abrir tela dentro do mainactivity

Tags: android

Estou fazendo uma calculadora de mecânica, porem queria fazer varias opções de calculo no `navigation drawer` e quando clicar a calculadora especifica carregasse na tela (a intenção é fazer uma `activity` para cada tipo de calculo), estou usando o código para abrir a `activity` de um calculo quando se clica na primeira opção do `navigation drawer`

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.calcRPM) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),calculorpm.class));
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas como podem ver nas imagens ele abre uma nova tela, sem o `drawer` e o menu lá em cima. como poderia fazer isso carregar como parte do app "principal"

Comment: Pesquise sobre fragments, voce vai ter apenas uma atividade e varios fragments que trocam o conteudo interno da atividade. Sua pergunta esta muito ampla pra oferecermos um codigo de resposta..

Comment: Vou da uma pesquisada, valeu

Comment: Eu não usaria fragmento porque limita muito a aplicação.
Você pode fazer uma BaseActivity, as outras atividades que precisem do navigation drawer devem estender ela.
No inicio da um pouco de trabalho, mas depois tudo fica mais fácil.
Da uma olhada nesse exemplo: http://mateoj.com/2015/06/21/adding-toolbar-and-navigation-drawer-all-activities-android/ Estava com a mesma dificuldade que você e foi ai que achei o caminho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para fazer isso, você não deve iniciar uma nova activity, quando clicar em um item no  navigation drawer. O que você deve fazer é trabalhar com fragmentos na MainActivity e substituir esse fragmento quando um item for selecionado ao invés de iniciar uma nova activity.

Na sua activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Na sua MainActivity

```
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
            else menuItem.setChecked(true);

            //Closing drawer on item click
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                //Replacing the main content with right fragment;
                case R.id.start:
                    if (startfragment == null) {
                        startfragment = new StartFragment();
                    }
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, startfragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.second:
                    if (secondfragment == null) {
                        secondfragment = new Secondfragment();
                    }
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, secondfragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;

                default:
                    if (startfragment == null) {
                        startfragment = new StartFragment();
                    }
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, startfragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;


            }
         }
    });
```

E o modelo de um fragmento

public class StartFragment extends Fragment {
    //Ui Elements

```
//Atributtes
private View view;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start, container, false);
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}}
```

Comment: Você vai precisar troca de Activity apenas se você for utilizar um Collapsing Toolbar, algo do gênero. Caso não, faça como pede os comentários a cima

Se for usar a troca de activitys, terá que usar drawer em todas as activity.

Comment: Criei um novo projeto e criei 2 fragmentos ( um com um textview escrito calculo rpm ), entendi a parte de colocar ele no menu, quando eu clico ele abre o fragmento, porem dessa forma: http://imgur.com/a/yE9TF com o conteudo do fragmento sobre o app bar e sobre o resto do app, como deixar ele parte do app ?

Comment: Consegui, foi só alterar o frame do main activity pro content main